# Screenshare browser (android <-> PC)

Tags: javascript, android, flask, webrtc, screensharing

Im looking for an screen-capture or screen-sharing API, which i can implement into my webapp.

Goal:
I render a webapp with flask on a raspberry and access it with an android tablet (chrome browser).
Now want to share my tablets screen (webpage) via internet, and view it in the browser of the pc.

i tried this example https://github.com/di/screenshare , but its working only locally i guess.
Or is this adaptable to share my browser of the tablet with the www?

Somebody an idea how to this?

Comment: You can specify the host in screen.py in https://github.com/di/screenshare to run on your specified server-ip. you can also attain what you want to do via using http server. I know in python you have file-transfer from http-server and nodejs will also have the same, in case screenshare does nt work for you.

Comment: There are tablet, raspi and pc. Now you want send screendump of tablet from tablet to pc. What has that to do wiht the raspi?

Comment: the tablet is connected to the AP of raspi. The raspi simultaniously is connected to the internet wifi. now i want to share the screen of the tablet via the flask websocket on the raspi.

Comment: @Patrick, Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

As of today WebRTC's Screen_Capture_API is not available for mobile, though you can receive screenshares from desktop.

Browser compatability for [Screen_Capture_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API):-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) is what you would need to use to capture a screen shot from a Web browser. It is available in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for information, but i still found and tried this API. Unfortunately Android isnt supporting the "getUserMedia" function.

is there some workaround or other method to share the screen (without any additional Android application) ?